# Path manipulation issue Fortify

Tags: java

Hi i have scanned an application using Fortify tool, in the generated reports i got path manipulation issue in the following method.

Note: In the report it is not showing the error line no. can anyone suggest me how to resove it?

```
private MimeMessage prepareMessage(EmailMessage req) throws EmailProviderException {
        long start=System.currentTimeMillis(),finish=0;

    try {
        MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();

        // create a multipart message
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);

        // set email addresses
        helper.setFrom(convertAddress(req.getFromAddress()));
        helper.setTo(convertAddress(req.getToAddress()));
        helper.setCc(convertAddress(req.getCcAddress()));
        helper.setBcc(convertAddress(req.getBccAddress()));

        // set subject and body
        helper.setSubject(req.getEmailSubject());
        String emailBody = req.getEmailBody();
        String emailMime = req.getEmailMimeType();

        MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource bodyDataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(emailBody, emailMime);
        messagePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(bodyDataSource));
        helper.getMimeMultipart().addBodyPart(messagePart);

        // add attachments
        List<EmailAttachment> lAttach = req.getEmailAttachment();
        if (lAttach != null) {
            for (EmailAttachment attachMnt: lAttach) {
                DataSource dSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachMnt
                        .getContent(), attachMnt
                        .getMimeType());
                helper.addAttachment(attachMnt.getFileName(), dSource);
            }
        }

        finish=System.currentTimeMillis();
        statsLogger.info(new FedExLogEntry("prepareMessage took {0}ms",new Object[]{finish-start}));    

        return message;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        // covers MessagingException, IllegalStateException, IOException, MailException
        String emsg = new StringBuilder("Unable to prepare smtp message.")
            .append("\n").append(req.toString()).toString();
        logger.warn(emsg, e);
        throw new EmailProviderException(emsg, e);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. If Fortify is having issues trying to show you the correct line where the issue exists, then it's possible that fortify ran in to a parsing error when it was scanning and rendering the results to your FPR. One thing you could try is to rescan your application under a different build-id and generate a new FPR. Beyond that, I don't know. Sorry.
Something else that I'd recommend would be to inspect your log file to see if there were any errors or warnings during translation/scan.

But after looking at your code sample, I'm thinking that Fortify is tainting the parameter `req` and flagging the the operation that is occurring when it's trying to add the file as an attachment. Most likely your sink is going to be at 
`helper.addAttachment(attachMnt.getFileName(), dSource);`

You'd want to validate the file names of the attachment themselves prior to trying to save them to disk.